# RegExp in ActionScript 3: How to exclude a complex prefix?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, prefix, lookbehind

AS3 RegExp engine (and ECMAScript based JavaScript) do not support **complex** "lookbehind" expressions. (lookahead expressions are fully supported.)

For example:

```
 (?<=<body>)(.*?)(?=<\/body>)
```

will work but;

```
(?<=<body\b[^>]*>)(.*?)(?=<\/body>)
```

will not work in AS3.

What I need is to match a complex prefix but exclude it in the final match.
In the example above; I'm trying to get the body contents in an HTML text but NOT the opening and closing body tags. And the actual test text looks like this:

```
<body bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
Some content here...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `var regExp:RegExp = /<body>(.*?)<\/body>/i;` as opposed to the 3 groups in your current regexp, so you're only capturing the body tag, you can then reference the match with either \1 or $1 depending on which function you're using:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=12_Using_Regular_Expressions_09.html

Answer (score 0):

This is coming from my JavaScript RegExp experience, but it should be relatively similar...

I don't think you need look-behind, you just need non-capturing groups.  They still match input, but they aren't captured by the match:

```
(?:<body\b[^>]*>)(.*?)(?:<\/body>)
```

When you do the match, the returned matches will only include the contents (but not the body opening/closing tags).

Comment: The regex codes I tried are in my post and also tried yours before.. They didn't work. But the problem is solved now. Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to quoo; the problem is solved in no time..

```
var re:RegExp = new RegExp(/(<body\b[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/body>)/gis); }
return strHTML.replace(re, "$2");
```

This returns only the content without the body tags.
No need to worry about lookbehinds and/or lookaheads..

Thanks to you all..

Comment: yay, glad to help, you could also do:

var re:RegExp = new RegExp(/<body\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/body>/gis); }
return strHTML.replace(re, "$1");

and then you're not saving the body open and close tags... but I suppose that doesn't matter too much.

Comment: Sure.. I set 3 groups beacuse in the function I give the user the choice to include tags or not.. If tags are included; I return "$1\r\n$2\r\n\$3".