# How to ignore whitespace in a regular expression subject string, but only if it comes after a newline?

Tags: regex, newline, whitespace

What is the best way to ignore the white space in a target string when searching for matches using a regular expression pattern, but only if the whitespace comes after a newline (\n)? For example, if my search is for "cats", I would want "c\n   ats" or "ca\n   ts" to match but not "c  ats" since the whitespace doesn't come after a newline. I can't strip out the whitespace beforehand because I need to find the begin and end index of the match (including any whitespace) in order to highlight that match and any whitespace needs to be there for formatting purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"What is the best way to ignore the white space in a target string when searching for matches using a regular expression pattern"

I would construct a regex dynamically, inserting a  `(?:\n\s)?` between each character.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $needed = 'cats';
my $regex = join '(?:\n\s)?' , split ( '',$needed );

print "\nRegex = $regex\n", '-'x40, "\n\n";

my $target = "
   cats
   c ats
   c\n ats
   ca ts
   ca\n ts
   cat s
   cat\n s
";

while ( $target =~ /($regex)/g)
{
    print "Found -  '$1'\n\n";
}
```

The output:

```
Regex = c(?:\n\s)?a(?:\n\s)?t(?:\n\s)?s
----------------------------------------

Found -  'cats'

Found -  'c
 ats'

Found -  'ca
 ts'

Found -  'cat
 s'
```

Comment: @neoneye, yes, `regex = /c(\n )?a(\n )?t(\n )?s/` is really the only way it can be done. (I don't have enough points to comment everywhere)

Comment: is there a difference between having the \s inside or outside the parentheses?  and what is the ? at the end for?

Comment: @Steven, inside the parentheses is a group. The '?' is a quantifier saying match the preceding group (or thing) 0 or once. So if there is nothing between the letters, it will match. You could also do (\n\s+)? Be aware that \s is whitespace and it includes newline, so \n\n between letters will pass. If your requirement is newline first then whitespace's without \n, then you could do (\n[^\S\n]+)?

Answer (score 3):

If the regex engine you're using supports lookaround assertions, use a positive lookbehind assertion to check for the presence of a preceding newline:

```
(?<=\n)\s
```

Comment: Surely that’s missing an `=`.

Comment: It’s an easy mistake to make; I’ve done it myself. There is a bit of a mismatch between the two sorts of lookarounds, with `(?=…)` and `(?!=…)` not quite matching up with `(?<=…)` and `(?<!…)`. There’s also potential confusion with the possessive group, `(?>…)`.

Comment: Thanks. So for multiple spaces, would it just be (?<=\n)\s* ?  Also, know offhand if the ECMA based AS3 RegExp engine supports lookbehinds?

Comment: @Steven: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900500/regexp-in-actionscript-3-how-to-exclude-a-complex-prefix) AS3 supports simple (but not complex) lookbehinds so this *should* work. For multiple spaces it would be `(?<=\n)\s+`

Comment: @BoltClock: I saw that post but then it seems to differ from the chart here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html  , will do some testing in AS3 to see

Comment: AS3 only claims to be compliant with the ECMAScript standard, but its regex support is actually provided by the PCRE library, so its feature set is much closer to PHP's than to JavaScript's.  That includes fixed-length lookbehinds like `(?<=\n)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a small ruby snippet based on the rules you have listed. Is this what you are looking for?

```
data = <<DATA
test1c\n atsOKexpected

test2ca\n tsOKexpected

test3catsOKexpected

test5ca tsBADexpected

test6 catsOKexpected

test7cats OKexpected
DATA

tests = data.split(/\n\n/)

regex = /c(\n )?a(\n )?t(\n )?s/

tests.each do |s|
  if s =~ regex
    puts "OK\n#{s}\n\n"
  else
    puts "BAD\n#{s}\n\n"
  end
end

# RESULTS
# OK
# test1c
#  atsOKexpected
# 
# OK
# test2ca
#  tsOKexpected
# 
# OK
# test3catsOKexpected
# 
# BAD
# test5ca tsBADexpected
# 
# OK
# test6 catsOKexpected
# 
# OK
# test7cats OKexpected
```